# Using a repeater with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repeater

How can I use a repeater with Entity Framework

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TagOp.aspx.cs" Inherits="canta.TagOp" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="canta.POCO.Objects" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%#(Container.DataItem as TagObject).IconPath %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=EnCantamEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="EnCantamEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="Tags">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The code above throws a `NullReferenceException`

This was my bad.
TagObject was my business layer and i tried to load it like it's an entity object.
I first loaded my data to `List<TagObject>` then binded the list to repeater.Then my problem solved.Guess I was still sleeping when i wrote that lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad. TagObject was my business layer and i tried to load it like it's an entity object. I first loaded my data to `List<TagObject>` then binded the list to repeater.Then my problem solved.Guess I was still sleeping when i wrote that lol :)